# Lack of skill in IT department putting strain on project

Tags: project-management, politics

Our company has an initiative to do a big project that will be 250000 in sales. We have a [CFT team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-functional_team) who are working on this the only part that is holding us back is the IT department.

We have spoken to a vendor who will guide us but the IT department has its doubt mainly because IT has never done this before. They want to wait six weeks til we test some things and then maybe they'll be able to implement.

I think I could work with the vendor but would need to sidestep the IT department. Should I do this or just wait six weeks for the possibility that they figure some things out on their end?

Comment: This is impossible for us to answer, we simply don't know the risk factors involved. If this is a billion dollar project that can't fail, and sidestepping the IT department adds no risk gives a different answer to: This project isn't that important, and it's fine if it fails, but if we sidestep the IT department and something goes wrong, the results will be catastrophic. Part of your job as a manager is to perform that risk assessment. I would encourage you to work with the IT department to find a way forward, they will probably know the risks better than you when it comes to their stuff.

Comment: And you may benefit from speaking with your manager, or a more senior manager who may be able to offer you tips on evaluating the risk. Also looking at company policies may help.

Comment: It wont be catastrophic. If there are hiccups along the way it wont be a big deal we simply adjust. I have made implementations like this before. Also we are working with a 3rd party company who has quality assurances in place.

Comment: My point here is nobody here can do your job for you. We are not the one getting the pay check... or getting fired. This question is more suited to Project Management Stack Exchange, though they are not going to make a decision for you either.

Comment: Regardless of your project's details, Shadow IT (bypassing the IT department because they're perceived to be an obstacle) is a net negative for the company, and is prone to exposing the company to additional risk and cost later on. It is not solely your place to evaluate that risk, you need to involve IT management and policies.

Comment: Some executive in your  company must have the authority to set priorities for both your team and your IT department. Have you tried to get that executive's help?

Comment: I think you should bypass IT and do it all by your self so when the project fails (and it will fail)  they can all point at you and laugh. I've seen so many people on the business side thinking IT is easy and we could do without. Please please please do it your self to stick to IT. This is going to be a good and painful lesson for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a manager, [your job is to evaluate risk](https://www.usenix.org/conference/lisa15/conference-program/presentation/dickson). So in this situation it is your risk to move forward before some work is done. Your IT department tells you work is necessary, your vendor says it's OK. You want this project done. You and all other actors work in own interests, and it is your job to make the judgement based on information you have. We can't make the decision for you.

To make your job easier, here is another observation. You write as if there are only 2 options (1-2). In reality there are many more options:

1. do what IT people say
2. do what vendor says
3. do part of what IT says, re-assess, then do what vendor says
4. start doing work with vendor, and do testing by IT, check in mid-way
5. outsource decision-making or evaluating to outside consulting person
6. establish isolated test environment for vendor to present their work, let in-house IT do their thing at the same time